# CircleCI builds fail while installing node and npm using below commands. Can anyone throw some light on this?

Tags: circleci

This step the build fails in circleci

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
node --version && npm -v

Exited with code exit status 60
CircleCI received exit code 60
```

Answer (score 0):

could you share your .circleci/config.yml? As without it, it's difficult to see what context you're attempted to do this. Since you're using node, would it not make more sense to use the node orb?